# java constantly sorted list with quick retrieval

Tags: java, sortedlist

I'm looking for a constantly sorted list in java, which can also be used to retrieve an object very quickly. PriorityQueue works great for the "constantly sorted" requirement, and HashMap works great for the fast retrieval by key, but I need both in the same list. At one point I had wrote my own, but it does not implement the collections interfaces (so can't be used as a drop-in replacement for a java.util.List etc), and I'd rather stick to standard java classes if possible.

Is there such a list out there? Right now I'm using 2 lists, a priority queue and a hashmap, both contain the same objects. I use the priority queue to traverse the first part of the list in sorted order, the hashmap for fast retrieval by key (I need to do both operations interchangeably), but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution...

Edit: I should add that I need to have the list sorted by a different comparator then what is used for retrieval by key; the list is sorted by a long value, the key retrieval is a String.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using `HashMap`, that implies that you have unique keys. Assuming that you want to order by those keys, `TreeMap` is your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... please see my edit a few seconds ago, I don't think TreeMap will work here.

Comment: @user85116 - no, it won't. But your question doesn't give enough information to give a good answer. For example, you say that you're currently using a PriorityQueue. Does that mean that you only care that the first item in the "list" is sorted? Or do you want a total ordering (in which case PriorityQueue is the wrong choice). If you edit your question with your actual use cases, then I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I fail to see why PriorityQueue is the wrong choice; as mentioned in my question, at times I need to traverse the first part of the list (not the whole list, just a few elements at the beginning) in sorted order (which PriorityQueue does quite nicely); my problem is that at other times, I need to grab an item from the list based on a key, and this lookup needs to be quick.

Comment: @user85116 - your question asks for different things. "Constantly sorted" implies that the entire list is sorted, which PriorityQueue does not do. For that matter, "list" implies certain behavior that your use of a Map contradicts. As I said above, if you describe your exact use case, rather that your current solution, people may be able to give you better suggestions. If you don't wish to do so, then all I can offer is "good luck."

Comment: PriorityQueue does exactly what is required; I can traverse the first part of the list, and know that each item that I get is in sorted order. If I add another item to the queue, I can then re-traverse the first few items, knowing that my new item will arrive in the correct order. This is a fact, sorry. I do agree that my use of the term "list" is a little fuzzy at times.

Comment: Edit; well I guess I was wrong, PriorityQueue's "iterator" does not guarantee an order; that's my mistake. Doesn't matter though, I've reworked some of that code already.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're talking about is a collection with an automatically-maintained index.

Try looking at [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) which use "list pipelines" to efficiently propagate changes -- their [SortedList](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/SortedList.html) class should do the job.

edit: missed your retrieval-by-key requirement. That can be accomplished with [GlazedLists.syncEventListToMap](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/GlazedLists.html#syncEventListToMap%28ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList,%20ca.odell.glazedlists.FunctionList.Function%29) and [GlazedLists.syncEventListToMultimap](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/GlazedLists.html#syncEventListToMultiMap%28ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList,%20ca.odell.glazedlists.FunctionList.Function%29) -- syncEventListToMap works if there are no duplicate keys, and syncEventListToMultimap works if there are duplicate keys. The nice part about this approach is that you can create multiple maps based on different indices.

---

If you want to use TreeMaps for indices -- which may give you better performance -- you need to keep your TreeMaps privately encapsulated within a custom class of your choosing, that exposes the interfaces/methods you want, and create accessors/mutators for that class to keep the indices in sync with the collection. Be sure to deal with concurrency issues (via `synchronized` methods or locks or whatever) if you access the collection from multiple threads.

---

edit: finally, if fast traversal of the items in sorted order is important, consider using [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) instead of TreeMap -- not for its concurrency, but for its fast traversal. [Skip lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) are linked lists with multiple levels of linkage, one that traverses all items, the next that traverses every K items on average (for a given constant K), the next that traverses every K<sup>2</sup> items on average, etc.

Answer (score 1):

TreeMap

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Go with a [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>
> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so I might be wrong, so consider this just an attempt.
Use TreeMap, wrap the key of this map as an object which has two attributes (the string which you use as the key in hashmap and the long which you use to maintain the sort order in PriorityQueue). Now for this object, override the equals and hashcode method using the string. Implement the comparable interface using the long.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you encapsulate your solution to a class that implements Collection or Map?
This way you could simply delegate the retrieval methods to the faster/better suiting collection. Just make sure that calls to write-methods (add/remove/put) will be forwarded to both collections. Remember indirect accesses, like iterator.remove(). Most of these methods are optional to implement, but you have to deactivate them (Collections.unmodifiableXXX will help here in most cases).